# jQueryMobile 1.4 - Multipages not working

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm coming from jQM 1.3 and am trying to replicate the functionality of having multiple pages in a single html document.

The code I copy-pasted from the [demo](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.1/pages-multi-page/#one) didn't work, it just displayed it as a normal html file (i.e. pages 1 and 2 were visible as soon as I loaded the document).

So I checked the demo website again and realized that the same thing was happening *with the demo site* on my laptop using Chrome. Here's what I see.

[image: demoScreenshot]

Here's my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

    <script src="http://192.168.2.101:8080/target/target-script-min.js#anonymous"></script>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css" />
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>

    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/jquery.mobile-1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css" />-->
    <title>Equipment Appraiser</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page1">
<div data-role="header">
  <h1>Page 1</h1>
</div>
<div role="main" class="ui-content">
  <a href="#page2" data-transition="slide" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline">Go To Page 2</a>
</div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
<div data-role="header">
  <h1>Page 2</h1>
</div>
<div role="main" class="ui-content">
  <a href="#page1" data-rel="back" data-transition="slide" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline">Go Back To Page 1</a>
</div>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.mobile-1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        function onDeviceReady() {
            init();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I clicked on the link to the demo, and In the network tab I'm getting a 404 for the jquery script, maybe that's the issue... Try downloading the actual scripts instead of linking to the cdn.

Comment: why `jquery-1.10.2.min.js` twice?

Comment: @Jack thx, it was the jquery that did it.